# Deploying a web application using the trial version on visual studio professional 2010 c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, exe

Does anyone know if it is possible to deploy a web application using the trial version on visual studio professional 2010 c#?

Or simply access the exe file?

I just need the project compiled so I can show it on another computer

edit:

Sorry its actually a windows form application. The 'debug and 'release' folders only exist as XML files not in the bin folder. Once I have ran the debug and release two new files are created in the bin folder but as application extensions saved as .dll

Please help

Comment: It is. If your actual question is "How", right-click the project and click Deploy / Publish. And no, you can't easily create an exe from a Web Application project.

Comment: It compiles every time you debug the app. You can find the exe in /bin/debug

Comment: @mituw16 - have you actually tried to find exe file for web application "in /bin/debug"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good catch, I didn't notice it was a web application :)

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio trials are fully featured for 90 days (last time I used one).

If you click the 'Quick Launch' search box in the upper right, and search for publish you will find it pretty fast.

Or you can right click the project and select publish. It is a pretty easy walkthrough from there.

[How to deploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can.I am assuming you are trying to use the trial version.

Answer (score 0):

yes you most certainly can....but if its the express version then not entirely because of some features not available in the express edition.